# How do you change a DECFLOAT to an INT using DB2 SQL?

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw

simply put I am trying to get rid of all of these DECFLOAT types in my database as a lot of reporting tools (such as Tableau) don't want to work with them. I am new to DB2 and have found a lot of literature online to go from any data type -> DECFLOAT, but nothing substantial about going from DECFLOAT -> INT.

Is this even possible? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting DECFLOAT to integer is supported according to [Table 2. Supported casts between built-in data types](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_castingbetweendatatypes.html#db2z_castingbetweendatatypes) and in fact you can achieve conversion to any of these: SMALLINT, INTEGER, BIGINT, DECIMAL, DECFLOAT, REAL, DOUBLE, CHAR, VARCHAR (depending on the data, e.g. there are limits to how large a smallint can be).

But why would you alter the table columns to integer? Why not DECIMAL instead? Or, don't alter your tables to suit BI products, instead use views that cast to decimal. You could also control rounding through views.

Whilst today's BI tools may have issues with this data type, that data type is based on standard EEE754r and in future versions of BI tools it may be less of a problem. Perhaps read [DECFLOAT: The data type of the future](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0801chainani/index.html) before altering any tables.

Comment: I glanced at the articles a week ago or so, but you are right, I have no specific need for INT, I just know that the DECFLOAT is formatted as a string of numbers and thought it would be the easiest to start with.

Also, sorry for not being clear, but this is in a view being created for the BI tool. I just have never run into DECFLOAT before and I am fairly new to DB2 so I wanted to know if there was any expected dataloss or anything of that nature when running a CAST or such.

Comment: If converting to  INT as you would lose the fractional portion.  Real, double or decimal would probably be better choices as they support fractional parts to differing precision. Nb. I was suggesting making views for BI use to avoid the difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Used_by_Already that you might be best updating your BI tools so that they work with `DECFLOAT`, or use `VIEW`s to convert to `INT` or `DECIMAL` (or even `FLOAT` !?) on the fly.

But if you do want to change the data type of an existing table, you can do that (with some restrictions), as the example below shows

```
create table df(df decfloat(16) not null primary key) organize by row;
insert into df values 1.0, 2.00, 3.120;
select * from df;
```

gives

```
DF                      
------------------------
                     1.0
                    2.00
                   3.120

  3 record(s) selected.
```

then

```
alter table df alter column df set data type integer;
```

returns

```
SQL0478N  The statement failed because one or more dependencies exist on the 
target object.  Target object type: "COLUMN". Name of an object that is 
dependent on the target object: "SQL180924130131030". Type of object that is 
dependent on the target object: "PRIMARY KEY".  SQLSTATE=42893
```

so

```
alter table df drop primary key;
alter table df alter column df set data type integer;
```

then

```
select * from df
```

gives

```
DF         
-----------
          1
          2
          3

  3 record(s) selected.
```

but

```
insert into df values 4
```

fails due to reorg pending

```
SQL0668N  Operation not allowed for reason code "7" on table "PAUL.DF".  
SQLSTATE=57016
```

so

```
call admin_cmd('reorg table df');
insert into df values 4;
alter table df add primary key (df);
select * from df;
```

gives

```
DF         
-----------
          1
          2
          3
          4

  4 record(s) selected.
```